# Get output of a function with exec and another with execSync to file and stdout

Tags: node.js

I'm currently working on a CL script and I'm facing an issue. I have the following code:

```js
exports.exec = function execLoc(string, options = "", extra, callback) {
    var test = child.exec(string, options);
    test.stdout.on('data', function(data){
        globalLogs(data, extra);
    })
    test.on('exit', function exit() {
        if (callback)
            callback();
    })
    test.on('error', function err() {
        console.error("Something went wrong:\n" + stderr);
    })
}

exports.execSync = function LocExecSync (string, extra)
{
    logOutput = child.execSync(string);
    globalLogs(logOutput.toString(), extra);
}
```

globalLogs() takes a string (stdout in this case), displays it on stdout and saves to a file too. I have two parallel processes at one point of the script and their output is only shown/saved at the end of each process (to avoid mixing the outputs) so I don't want live output. However for child.execSync() it doesn't show a live stdout, which I want to. I've been trying to solve this issue for a while now with no success. I thought a simple:

```
child.execSync(string, {stdio:[0,process.stdout,2]})
   process.stdout.on('data', function(data){
   globalLogs(data);
})
```

would work, but this causes the parallel processes stdout not to show on terminal but being saved on the file and the child.execSync stdout to show on terminal live but not being saved on the file. Putting the process.stdout.on() outside the function, makes everything show properly on the terminal, but the file doesn' have the "live" entries from stdout...

This may be a simple issue, but I'm new at programming in general and haven't been able to find or apply a working solution. I've tried CreateWriteStream, piping, having the function async but put a mechanism for the main script to wait until all the operations of the exported function end, all with no success. I would appreciate some help please :)